# How to wait for gitlab downstream pipelines to finish before going to next stage?

Tags: gitlab, cicd, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm not sure this is the way to proceed, but I'm starting using downstream pipelines.
I have 3 projects :

- Project A : web-frontend-1
- Project B : web-frontend-2
- Project C : global-e2e-testing

I'm setting up a CI pipeline on Project C which should do :

- Run main pipeline of Project A, with var TESTING=true (that is building docker images)
- Run main pipeline of Project B, with var TESTING=true (that is building docker images)
- Deploy on testing environment (it's pulling docker images, and relaunching project)
- Run e2e tests on testing environment

Here is my Project C `.gitlab-ci.yml` (upstream pipeline) :

```yml
stages:
- build-testing
- deploy
- test

build-project-a-testing:
  stage: build-testing
  trigger:
    project: workspace/project-a
  variables:
    TESTING: true

build-project-b-testing:
  stage: build-testing
  trigger:
    project: workspace/project-b
  variables:
    TESTING: true

deploy-testing:
  stage: deploy
  tags: ["testing-runner"]
  script:
    - echo "deploying..."

playwright-firefox:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - npm i
    - npx playwright install
  script:
    - npx playwright test --project=firefox --workers=1
  tags:
    - run-playwright
  artifacts:
    name: playwright-report-firefox
    paths:
      - playwright-report
      - results.xml
    reports:
      junit: results.xml
    expire_in: 1 week
    allow_failure: true
```

The issue I have is that the downstream pipeline are launched but without waiting them for ending.
So deployment job, would deploy an old container image, and testing is not relevant.

Is there a way to wait for downstream pipeline to finish ?
I can "reverse" the order of which project is downstream / upstream, but since I have two projects to build, the issue would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy keyword is the solution :

From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#triggerstrategy) :

> ```yml
> trigger_job:
>   trigger:
>     include: path/to/child-pipeline.yml
>     strategy: depend
> ```
>
> In this example, jobs from subsequent stages wait for the triggered pipeline to successfully complete before starting.